# transferring files from a subdirectory

Tags: python, directory

I have a subdirectory "update" and I need to move all files and folders from it to the current directory, removing all files and folders from the current directory.  The problem is that there are a lot of subfolders in the subdirectory and I can't figure out how to move them all.

Answer (score 2):

[`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) recursively moves files and folders.

If you wish to copy the internal directory and extract everything, use the following line:

```
shutil.copytree("update", ".", dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

You may then safely remove the "update" directory:

```
shutil.rmtree("update")
```

---

If you wish to clear the current directory, I would first move the update directory outside the current one, delete the current, and then rename.

Keep in mind, that if it's your current directory, I'm guessing the directory would be in use as Python is from it, so you can't really delete that.